# How to combine a stateful browser creating tabular data with a Wicket web application?

Tags: ajax, json, wicket

I am trying to write a wicket client, which is some what stateful. This gives me some head aches as I have a form presenting some tabular data. The user must be able to add/remove rows to the data, without provoking an Ajax request to the server every time a row has been added/delete. I have implemented the add row functionality in the browser by usage of jQuery which works perfectly. The question is how I get this to work with Wicket?

My html snippet:

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    ...
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr wicket:id="voyagePlan">
      <td><input wicket:id="berth.name" type="text"/></td>
      <td><input wicket:id="berth.position.lattitude" type="text"/></td>
      <td><input wicket:id="berth.position.longitude" type="text" /></td> 
  <td><input wicket:id="arrival" type="text"/></td>
      <td><input wicket:id="departure" type="text"/></td>
      <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></td>
</tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My Java code:

```
private CompoundPropertyModel<List<Voyage>> model = new CompoundPropertyModel<>(new VoyageModel());

public MyForm(String id) {
  super(id, "MyForm");
  WebMarkupContainer modalBody = new WebMarkupContainer("modalBody", model);
  add(modalBody);

  final PropertyListView<Voyage> lv = new PropertyListView<Voyage>("voyagePlan") {
    @Override
    protected void populateItem(ListItem<Voyage> item) {
      item.add(new TextField<String>("key"));
      item.add(new TextField<String>("berth.name"));
      item.add(new TextField<String>("berth.position.lattitude"));
      item.add(new TextField<String>("berth.position.longitude"));
      item.add(new TextField<String>("arrival"));
      item.add(new TextField<String>("departure"));
    }
  };

  modalBody.add(lv);

  saveLink = new AjaxSubmitLink("save") {
    @Override
    protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
      shipService.saveVoyageInformation(model.getObject());
      target.add(this.getParent());
    }
  };
  add(saveLink);
}

public class VoyageModel extends LoadableDetachableModel<List<Voyage>> {
  @Override
  protected List<Voyage> load() {
    return myService.getVoyage(mmsi);
  }
}
```

Having this code, then problem more specifically becomes, how to update the List instance when new rows has been added and submitted? Currently only changes to existing rows  are updated. New rows are never saved into the database.

I have thought of writing functionality for sending data as json by following the approach described here: http://thewicketevangelist.blogspot.dk/2011/12/marrying-wicket-and-jquery-ajax.html. If I understand correctly, this will however mean that form input field validations like TextField.setRequired etc are no longer usable. Is that correctly understood?

I would like an approach close to the normal Wicket web request handling, with all the benefits of input validation etc.

Comment: Can the users add cells to voyagePlan or do they add an entire new tr?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, what you want is to create a dynamic form, "dynamic" meaning that the structure of the form is defined and potentially changed during runtime.

That can of course be done with Wicket but it is not easy with any server side web framework since the client-side representation has to be kept in sync with the server-side Java components. The JQuery-approach sending JSON to the server is somewhat bypassing the Wicket features, as you already mentioned, and you would have to re-code some things that Wicket usually already does for you.

As I see it, you have the following options:

- you can code your own "dynamic form" component with Wicket, which you already started in your code snippet. You would have to solve several problems like the one you already stumbled upon: how to update your Wicket List component (perhaps my blog post will help with that: http://tom.hombergs.de/2013/03/advanced-wicket-dynamic-listview-within.html).
- you can use Wicked Forms (http://wicked-forms.org) which is a library I am currently developing to create dynamic forms with Wicket. It's not released yet, but you can use it at your own risk (or you can have a look at the sources and build your own). There is a showcase on the project homepage which shows the features. Have a look if it meets your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it with fragments but not without Ajax.
Create a fragment representing a voyagePlan row.
Change your PropertyListView to populate fragments.
Create an AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior that generates a new Voyage object + fragment, adds it to your PropertyListView and adds your modalBody to target to reload the list.
Override renderHead to add a javascripts function that triggers the AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior
Have jquery call that javascript function when the user wants to add a new row.